# Solr post filter: How to know which doc is the last one

Tags: solr

I'm following [this guide](https://lucidworks.com/post/custom-security-filtering-in-solr/) to create a post filter for solr. It works 99% well. There is 1% remain  that I need to detect which `doc` is the last doc passed to my `collect` function (to apply special check).

Any help / any clue is precious.

Thanks

```
public void collect(int doc) throws IOException {
    if (isAllowed(acls[doc], user, groups)) super.collect(doc);
}
```

Comment: What's the reason why you need to know if something is the last doc? Do you need to know that the doc is the last one, or that there's no more documents coming? Could it be implemented in some other way? (I haven't found anything that allows you to know if a doc is the last one, but it might be possible through the leaf context or something else that I don't know of).

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh,  I think `it's the last one` is same `there's no more documents coming`. If it's impossible to detect the last doc, I need to change to another approach.

Comment: My point is that there's a difference between knowing that a document is the last one when you're running the collector and for example your collector being deallocated (i.e. finalizing of the object happening). There might be workarounds depending on what kind of task you want to perform - i.e. closing a database handle can be worked around by using a pool and a timeout instead of knowing if a document is the last one. That's why _context_ for why this is necessary is important.